# Error with summarise(): Can't promote group 1 to numeric

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(qnrA1 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), qnrB19 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), qnrB6 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), qnrB60 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), qnrS1 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), qnrS2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), qnrS4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), gyrA = c("S83L", "S83L", "S83L", "S83L", "S83L", "S83L, D87N", 
"S83L", "S83L", "S83A", "S83L, D87N"), gyrB = c("0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), parC = c("0", "S80I", "0", 
"0", "0", "S80I", "0", "0", "0", "S58I"), parE = c("0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "D475E", "0", "0"), marR = c("1", "1", 
"0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0"), CIP = c(0.25, 1, 0.5, 
0.25, 0.25, 8, 0.12, 0.25, 0.06, 16), NAL = c(128L, 256L, 256L, 
256L, 64L, 256L, 64L, 128L, 32L, 256L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I want to do is to group by all columns except the CIP/NAL columns, then do an equivalent of count(), but I want to create new columns with the values found in CIP/NAL for each group. If the max value in CIP is equal to the NAL value, I just want that value in the column. If they are not equal, I want them both in the same row and column, separated by a "-".
I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-c(CIP, NAL))) %>%
  summarise(CIP = ifelse(min(as.numeric(CIP)) == max(as.numeric(CIP)),
                         median(as.numeric(CIP)),
                         paste(min(as.numeric(CIP)), max(as.numeric(CIP)), sep = "-")),
            n = n())
```

However, when i run this, i get the following error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `CIP` can't promote group 1 to numeric
```

The error seems to happen when min(as.numeric(CIP)) =/= max(as.numeric(CIP)) for each group, as it seems to work fine when I change the paste line to just "0" in the ifelse function. Any suggestions as to what this error means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not conversant with the error but if you look at the `ifelse` statement, you are getting a numeric value in case the condition is true and a character if it is false. I think that's leading to the error. You could try this:

```
df %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-c(CIP, NAL))) %>%
  summarise(CIP = ifelse(min(as.numeric(CIP)) == max(as.numeric(CIP)),
                         as.character(median(as.numeric(CIP))),
                         paste(min(as.numeric(CIP)), max(as.numeric(CIP)), sep = "-")),
            n = n())
```